# Decompressing a tarball containing a single root directory while renaming the root destination

Tags: shell, unix, archive, tar, compression

Here is the scenario:

```bsh
$ wget "http://foo.bar/repository/nightly/src/foo-latest.tar.gz"
$ tar -xzf foo-lastest.tar.gz
$ ls # the archive root contained a single directory named after software name and the build date
foo-20140115-0024
```

What you want is that in the end, the extracted files are placed in the directory *foo*, instead of *foo-20140115-0024*. You can of course move the directory once decompressed :

```bsh
$ mv `tar -tvzf foo-latest.tar.gz | head -n1 | awk '{print $6}'` foo
```

Here is the question: is there a shorter/proper to perform the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ tar -C foo --strip-components=1 -xzf foo-latest.tar.gz
```

First we create output directory.
After that we use `-C` to extract archive to that directory and `--strip-components` to get rid of root directory from archive.